# Dockerfile ADD failed : No Source files were specified

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, pydev

I have a python project created in eclipse. I am creating for first time a Dockerfile.The Docker build always fails showing this

> ADD failed: no source files were specified

I am copying the project directory and adding pydev packages with python modules using ADD command.Below is the python project structure. How to ADD all modules in Dockerfile?

```
-Myproject_rootdirectory
  -- Client
    - __init__.py
    - Main.py

  --Subscriber1
   - domain1
     - __init__.py
     - d2.py
  - domain2
     - __init__.py
     - d2.py
  - __init__.py

 --Subscriber2
   - domain3
     - __init__.py
     - d3.py
   - domain4
     - __init__.py
     - d4.py
   - __init__.py
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It generally is recommended to use `COPY` before `ADD`, because it serves a lesser purpose and is somewhat more lightweight.

To copy your whole directory into the image, just add the following line after editing:

```
 COPY . /path/to/dir/in/image
```

Some helpful links to start writing dockerfiles:

[Reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/)

[Best Practices](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/)

[Postgresql example](https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/postgresql_service/)

Answer (score 5):

In a Java project, the problem was the lack of a JAR file in the **target** folder. It was necessary to make (in the case of maven) the **mvn clean package**, and then make the **docker run** command.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same error message.
It was a `.dockerignore` next to my Dockerfile wich was ignoring my file.

Answer (score -1):

I got the same error for my spring boot microservice.
I have rebuild my microservice using

```
mvn clean install
```

And run the docker build command again, this worked for me.

Comment: The answer was right but not properly written